# How do we secure socket connections/messages to a local webserver?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, certificate

I am implementing a Local Websocket server in Express nodeJS. Data is sent from the front-end to the server by creating a `new WebSocket(ws://<private_ip>:3000);` as soon as `<private_ip>:3000` is opened in a phone browser. (notice the **ws**)

This Local Websocket server will not be hosted on a public server but only on **personal machines** e.g. your own windows/mac machine. The reasoning behind this is not related to this post and will be omitted.

I have a basic understanding of how certificates work. I know that `self-signed certificates` are usually imported to the browser to be trusted. The goal is to use something like `new WebSocket(wss://<private_ip>:3000);` at the client side (notice the **wss**).

I fail to understand how the socket client created by code will trust a `self-signed certificate`, hence the question: is there a way to secure the connection/communication to/with a locally hosted Webserver

Comment: Do you really need wss if the traffic is only on the local machine?

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, I am not in a position to disclose the underlying details but I do need to secure communication between two machines

Comment: If you want a browser to trust a self-signed certificate, it seems you will have to import that cert into the browser as a trusted certificate.  See [Getting Chrome to accept self signed cert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate) for several approaches.

Comment: Yes in the browser you trust a new root certificate by importing. What I am looking for is a secure communication between code. I am not using Chrome. Does it make sense to have local certificates and private keys that are used by nodeJS on each machine?

Comment: What is the front-end environment then?  You've said it's not Chrome, so what is it.  Environments each have their own way of importing certificates that they will trust.

Comment: @jfriend00 i am using nodeJS to create my Websocket client and express server, more specifically they are running inside electron which is similar to chrome